# ¿Cómo ordenar una matriz bidimensional por columnas en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ordenamiento, matrices

¿Cómo ordenar una matriz bidimensional por columnas en *Javascript*?

Por ejemplo, tengo esta matriz 2D, es decir, un array *JSON* en forma de tabla, y quiero ordenarlo por columnas:

```
var matriz = [
//Columnas:   0 1 2 3 4
/*Filas: 0*/ [9,5,3,2,7],
/*       1*/ [7,9,5,4,3],
/*       2*/ [8,4,6,0,1]
            ]
```

Accediendo al elemento `array[2][4]` nos devuelve `1`, es decir, fila `2`, columna `4`.

Lo que quiero hacer es ordenar, por ejemplo, la columna `3`, pero sin cambiar la secuencia en cada fila, y quedaría de esta manera:

```
var matriz = [
//Columnas:   0 1 2 3 4
/*Filas: 0*/ [8,4,6,0,1]
/*       1*/ [9,5,3,2,7],
/*       2*/ [7,9,5,4,3],
            ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En JavaScript tienes la función `sort` que ordenará los elementos del array que le pases (y una matriz bidimensional bi es más que un array de arrays), y que puede tomar como parámetro una función de comparación personalizada. Dicha función recibirá los arrays que se van a comparar, por lo que sólo haría falta saber qué índice de columna se debe comparar.

Entonces podrías ordenar la matriz por columnas en un simple proceso de dos pasos:

1. Definir la columna por la que quieres ordenar,
2. Llamar a `sort` con una función de ordenación personalizada.

Algo como esto (idealmente la función de comparación debería tener algún tipo de precondiciones para asegurarse de que el índice y los arrays son válidos):

```js
var matriz = [
//Columnas:   0 1 2 3 4
/*Filas: 0*/ [9,5,3,2,7],
/*       1*/ [7,9,5,4,3],
/*       2*/ [8,4,6,0,1]
            ];

// definimos la función de comparación
function compare(a, b) {
  // comparamos los elementos en los índices indicados
  return (a[indiceOrdenacion] >= b[indiceOrdenacion]) ? 1 : -1;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(matriz));

// paso 1: especificar la columna que se usará para ordenar
var indiceOrdenacion = 3;
// paso 2: llamar a la ordenación con nuestra función de comparación propia
matriz = matriz.sort(compare);

console.log(JSON.stringify(matriz));
```

Comment: Hice una adaptación a esta respuesta, para que `indiceOrdenacion`, no la reciba desde la nada. http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/49165/13558

Answer (score 4):

Para ordenar la matriz, uso la búsqueda binaria. Este tipo de búsqueda hace que se encuentre un valor en el menor número de pasos posibles aplicado a una secuencia ordenada. Por ejemplo, si quiero buscar el 66 entre 100 números, lo que hago es, primero, digo la mitad de la cantidad total, es decir, pregunto si es 50. La respuesta a eso es, *"No, es mayor a 50"*, luego pregunto el promedio entre 50 y 100, es decir, ¿Es 75?, no, es menor, y así sucesivamente.

Busco el **66**, me voy aproximando cada vez más... 100 50 75 62 68 65 ***66***. Esto es similar a lo que hacemos inconscientemente al buscar una palabra en un diccionario de papel, nadie busca página por página, sino que se va aproximando.

Lo que hago para ordenar la matriz es, primero declaro una matriz vacía, y voy insertando de manera ordenada cada fila. De esta manera queda ordenada la columna indicada sin alterar la secuencia en cada fila.

Para insertar una fila, primero busco la posición indicada para insertarla, es decir, la fila a insertar quedará al principio de la matriz, o al final, o de lo contrario entre otras dos filas.

También, es posible indicar si quiero ordenar la matriz de manera descendente. De lo contrario, será ascendente. La función `compara`, justamente compara dos números. Si el primero es menor al segundo, devuelve 1, si son iguales, devuelve 0, y si el primero es mayor al segundo, devuelve -1... Todo eso, si `esDescentente` es `false`, pero si es `true`, el -1 es 1, y viceversa.

Código:

```js
var matriz = [
//Columnas:   0 1 2 3 4
/*Filas: 0*/ [9,5,3,2,7],
/*       1*/ [7,9,5,4,3],
/*       2*/ [8,4,6,0,1]
   ]

function compara(uno,dos,esDescendente)
{
 var primero=uno*=1
 var segundo=dos*=1
 var devuelve=0
 if(primero<segundo){devuelve= -1}
 if(primero>segundo){devuelve=  1}
 if( esDescendente ){devuelve*=-1}
 return devuelve
}
function buscar(matriz,valor,columna,compara,esDescendente)
{
 var comparado=0
 var i=0
 var j=matriz.length-1
 var fila=Math.floor((i+j)/2)
 var devuelve
 while(i<=j)
 {
  comparado=compara(matriz[fila][columna],valor,esDescendente)
  if(comparado== 1){j=fila-1}
  if(comparado==-1){i=fila+1}
  if(comparado== 0){break}
  fila=Math.floor((i+j)/2)
 }
 array_fila=matriz[fila]
 if(array_fila!=undefined)
 {
  comparado=compara(array_fila[columna],valor,esDescendente)
 }
 devuelve=fila+(comparado==-1)
 if(devuelve<0){devuelve=0}
 return devuelve
}
function insertarOrdenado(matriz,valor,columna,compara,esDescendente)
{
 var posición=buscar(matriz,valor[columna],columna,compara,esDescendente)
 var inicio=matriz.slice(0,posición)
 var medio=[valor]
 var fin=matriz.slice(posición)
 var devuelve=inicio.concat(medio).concat(fin)
 return devuelve
}
function ordenar(matriz,columna,compara,esDescendente)
{
 var devuelve=[]
 for(var i=0;i<matriz.length;i++)
 {
  devuelve=insertarOrdenado(
   devuelve,matriz[i],columna,compara,esDescendente
  )
 }
 return devuelve
}
ascendente=ordenar(matriz,3,compara,false)
console.log(JSON.stringify(ascendente).replace(/\],\[|\[\[|]]/g,"\n"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Adaptando la [respuesta de Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/49122/13558), lo que no me convenció del todo, es que la variable `indiceOrdenacion` (en mi caso lo nombro `columna`) la recibe desde la nada. Para que esto no pase, hago una función que genere la función `compare` (lo nombro `compara`, en español).

La función `genera_compara` recibe dos argumentos, uno es `columna`, y el otro es `esDescendente` (un booleano), y devuelve una función. Dejo algunos ejemplos:

- `generar_compara(3,true )` devuelve `function anonymous(a,b){return a[3]>=b[3]?1:-1}`
- `generar_compara(4,false)` devuelve `function anonymous(a,b){return a[4]>=b[4]?-1:1}`

Además hice que la función `ordenar` no cambie los valores de la matriz original, sino que la copia.

Código:

```js
var matriz = [
//Columnas:   0 1 2 3 4
/*Filas: 0*/ [9,5,3,2,7],
/*       1*/ [7,9,5,4,3],
/*       2*/ [8,4,6,0,1]
            ];

function generar_compara(columna,esDescendente)
{
 var menos=1-2*esDescendente
 var devuelve="return a["+columna+"]>=b["+columna+"]?"+menos+":"+(-menos)
 return Function("a","b",devuelve)
}
function ordenar(matriz,columna,esDescendente)
{
 var compara=generar_compara(columna,esDescendente)
 return matriz.slice(0).sort(compara)
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(matriz).replace(/\],\[|]]/g,"\n").slice(2))
copia=ordenar(matriz,3,false)
console.log(JSON.stringify(copia ).replace(/\],\[|]]/g,"\n").slice(2))
```