# ¿Cómo ordenar una matriz 2D por varias columnas en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ordenamiento, matrices

La semana pasada, es decir, el 13 de Febrero del 2017, hice una pregunta.

[¿Cómo ordenar una matriz bidimensional por columnas en Javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49116/c%c3%b3mo-ordenar-una-matriz-bidimensional-por-columnas-en-javascript)

Pero eso funciona para ordenar una sola columna. Cuando dos elementos de la columna a ordenar son iguales, debería poder ordenar por otra columna ese sector, pero no lo hace.

Lo matriz que quiero ordenar es la siguiente:

```
var matriz = [
//Columnas:    0 1 2 3 4
/*Filas:  0*/ [9,5,3,2,7],
/*        1*/ [7,9,5,4,3],
/*        2*/ [8,4,6,0,1],
/*        3*/ [9,9,6,2,1]
             ]
```

Con el algoritmo actual, ordenando la columna **3**, la respuesta es la siguiente:

```
var matriz = [
//Columnas:    0 1 2 3 4
/*Filas:  0*/ [7,9,5,4,3],
/*        1*/ [9,5,3,2,7],
/*        2*/ [9,9,6,2,1],
/*        3*/ [8,4,6,0,1]
             ]
```

No está tan mal, está ordenado `4 2 2 0`, pero las filas que tienen el **2**, deberían estar ordenadas por las columnas que yo quiera.

Para que sea exacto, la función que ordena, debería recibir un array (una secuencia) con todas las columnas que quiero ordenar, por ejemplo, `[3,0,1,2,4]`. Esto significa que primero ordena por la columna 3, en caso de ser iguales (el **2**), ordena esas por la 0, pero el **9** también es igual, así que ordena por el 1, y quedaría ordenada, pero por las dudas, también ordena por 1, 2 y 4.

Además, para que sea más general, estaría bueno ir cambiando si la columna es ascendente o descendente, para esto, en vez de un array debería ser una matriz, la primera columna es el número de la columna a ordenar, y la segunda columna es un booleano que indica `true` si es descendente, y `false` si es descendente.

```
var columnas = [//  Columna - esDescendente
                  [   3,        true ],
                  [   0,        true ],
                  [   1,        true ],
                  [   2,        false],
                  [   4,        false]
]
```

Con este parámetro, el resultado debería ser el siguiente:

```
var matriz = [
//Columnas:    0 1 2 3 4
/*Filas:  0*/ [7,9,5,4,3],
/*        1*/ [9,9,6,2,1],
/*        2*/ [9,5,3,2,7],
/*        3*/ [8,4,6,0,1]
             ]
```

El criterio de ordenamiento no es estático, sino que es generado por una función.

```js
function generar_compara(columna,esDescendente)
{
  var menos=1-2*esDescendente
  var devuelve="return a["+columna+"]>=b["+columna+"]?"+menos+":"+(-menos)
  return Function("a","b",devuelve)
}
console.log(generar_compara(0,true))
console.log(generar_compara(1,false))
```

Según los argumentos que le indico, me genera una función **criterio** diferente.

- `0, false` -> `function anonymous(a,b/**/) {return a[0]>=b[0]?-1:1}`
- `1,  true` -> `function anonymous(a,b/**/) {return a[1]>=b[1]?1:-1}`

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo sería el criterio si quiero ordenar, por ejemplo, de la siguiente manera `[3,true],[0,true],[1,true],[2,false],[4,false]`? y partiendo de la función ejemplo, ¿Cómo puedo construir un generador de funciones similares, para que sea más general?

Comment: No me queda claro esta parte: _"y quedaría ordenada, pero por las dudas, también ordena por 1, 2 y 4."_. Si bien, `1` no va (ya se orden por esta columna), no entiendo a que filas y de que forma, estos 2 últimos afectarían.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo En el ejemplo que puse en concreto solo es necesario ordenar por las columnas 3, 0 y 1, pero como no se sabe de antemano, es recomendable recibir la lista completa de las columnas, el 2 y el 4 no afecta, por lo que habría que poner un break (o tratar de ordenarlo aunque no afecte).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ampliando la respuesta del mismo OP, no necesitas usar Function (que es una forma de eval y es una mala práctica, además de ser poco intuitiva para el lector). Puedes lograr lo mismo simplemente devolviendo una expresión de función.

```
var columnas=[[3,true],[0,true],[1,true],[2,false],[4,false]]

function generar_compara(columnas)
{
    var criterio = function(a,b)
    {
        for(var i=0;i<columnas.length;i++)
        {
            var columna=columnas[i][0]
            var menos=1-2*columnas[i][1]
            if(a[columna]>b[columna]){return +menos}
            if(a[columna]<b[columna]){return -menos}
        }
        return 0
    };
    return criterio;
}
function ordenar(matriz,columnas)
{
    var compara=generar_compara(columnas)
    return matriz.slice(0).sort(compara)
}
```

Y por lo mismo se puede expresar como:

```
function ordenar(matriz,columnas)
{
    var criterio = function(a,b)
    {
        for(var i=0;i<columnas.length;i++)
        {
            var columna=columnas[i][0]
            var menos=1-2*columnas[i][1]
            if(a[columna]>b[columna]){return +menos}
            if(a[columna]<b[columna]){return -menos}
        }
        return 0
    };

    return matriz.slice(0).sort(criterio);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

una posible solución es usar una función recursiva que recorra la columna buscando la fila mayor y de no encontrarla buscar en la siguiente.
Para controlar que columnas comprobar puedes usar una matriz de control, del mismo tamaño que la matriz a comprobar, con true o false según convenga usarlas o ignorarlas en el bucle.
Por ejemplo:

```js
 var matriz = [
 //Columnas:    0 1 2 3 4
 /*Filas:  0*/ [9,5,3,2,7],
 /*        1*/ [7,9,5,4,3],
 /*        2*/ [8,4,6,0,1],
 /*        3*/ [9,9,6,2,1]
             ];

 function ordenaMatriz2d (matriz2d,matrizOrden,matrizControl){
  if (!matrizControl){
   matrizControl = [];
   matrizControl.length = matriz2d.length;
   matrizControl.fill(true);
  }
  var matrizOrdenada = [];
  
  var filaMayor = function (matriz2d,matrizOrden,matrizControl,indiceOrden){
   if (!indiceOrden) indiceOrden = 0;
   var columna=matrizOrden[indiceOrden];
   var mayor=null;
   for (let i=0; i<matriz2d.length;i++){
    if (!matrizControl[i]) continue;
    if (mayor===null || matriz2d[i][columna]>matriz2d[mayor][columna]) mayor=i;
    else if (matriz2d[i][columna]==matriz2d[mayor][columna]) {
     if (indiceOrden>=matrizOrden.length) continue;
     var matrizControlRecursivo=[];
     matrizControlRecursivo.length=matrizControl.length;
     matrizControlRecursivo.fill(false);
     matrizControlRecursivo[i]=true;
     matrizControlRecursivo[mayor]=true;
     mayor = filaMayor (matriz2d,matrizOrden,matrizControlRecursivo,indiceOrden+1);
    }
   }
   return mayor;
  }
  var mayor;
  for (let i=0; i<matriz2d.length; i++) {
   mayor=filaMayor(matriz2d,matrizOrden,matrizControl);
   matrizOrdenada.push(matriz2d[mayor]);
   matrizControl[mayor]=false;
  }
  return matrizOrdenada;
 }
 var matrizOrdenada=ordenaMatriz2d(matriz,[3,0,1,2,4]);
 for (let i=0; i<matrizOrdenada.length; i++)
  document.write(matrizOrdenada[i]+"<br>");
```

El tema de elegir el orden de la columna, seria añadir la dirección en la matriz de control y gestionarlo desde la función recursiva con un condicional.

Answer (score 3):

La función criterio tendría que recorrer la matriz `columnas`, cada elemento de esa matriz contiene un par de valores, como esta fila `[3,true]`, el `3` es la columna, el `true` es indica si es descendente.

Debería quedar algo así:

```
function criterio(a,b,columnas)
{
    for(var i=0;i<columnas.length;i++)
    {
        var columna=columnas[i][0]
        var menos=1-2*columnas[i][1]
        if(a[columna]>b[columna]){return +menos}
        if(a[columna]<b[columna]){return -menos}
    }
    return 0
}
```

Pero como el método `sort` no envía el parámetro `columnas`, hay que generar la función con `Function`, así que convierto la función en una cadena de texto, insertando en el medio la matriz `columnas` con `JSON.stringify`.

```js
var matriz = [
//Columnas:    0 1 2 3 4
/*Filas:  0*/ [9,5,3,2,7],
/*        1*/ [7,9,5,4,3],
/*        2*/ [8,4,6,0,1],
/*        3*/ [9,9,6,2,1]
             ]
             
var columnas=[[3,true],[0,true],[1,true],[2,false],[4,false]]

function generar_compara(columnas)
{
 var devuelve="\t"+"var columnas="+JSON.stringify(columnas)+"\n\t"+
  "for(var i=0;i<columnas.length;i++){"+"\n\t\t"+
   "var columna=columnas[i][0]"+"\n\t\t"+
   "var menos=1-2*columnas[i][1]"+"\n\t\t"+
   "if(a[columna]>b[columna]){return +menos}"+"\n\t\t"+
   "if(a[columna]<b[columna]){return -menos}"+"\n\t"+
  "};return 0"
 return Function("a","b",devuelve)
}
function ordenar(matriz,columnas)
{
 var compara=generar_compara(columnas)
 return matriz.slice(0).sort(compara)
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(matriz).replace(/\],\[|]]/g,"\n").slice(2))
copia=ordenar(matriz,columnas)
console.log(JSON.stringify(copia ).replace(/\],\[|]]/g,"\n").slice(2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Para poder ordenar por distintos `criterios`, en lugar de suministrar un arreglo con `[3,false]`, donde `3` es la columna y `false` indica si es `ASC o DESC`, se me ocurre que para hacerlo más *"flexible"* podrías suministrar un arreglo con `[3,fn]`, donde `fn` es una función que vamos a aplicar para ordenar la matriz.

Por ejemplo:

```
function asc(a, b) {
  return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0);
}

function desc(a, b) {
  return a > b ? -1 : (a < b ? 1 : 0);
}

var criterios = [
  [3, desc],
  [0, desc],
  [1, desc],
  [2, asc],
  [4, asc]
];
```

Luego, usando este arreglo de *"criterios"*, quedaría por ordenar la matriz aplicando el primer criterio del arreglo y dependiendo de que si en las filas ordenadas los valores en columna se repiten aplicar el siguiente criterio sobre estas.

Demo:

```js
function ordenar(matriz, criterios) {
  var arreglo = matriz.slice(0),
    reglas = criterios.slice(0),
    regla = reglas.shift(),
    columna = regla[0],
    criterio = regla[1];
  
  // Ordenamos por el criterio y columna
  arreglo.sort(function(a, b) {
    return criterio(a[columna], b[columna]);
  });

  // Verificamos filas iguales
  var actual,
    anterior,
    count = 1;
  for(var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    actual = arreglo[i][columna];
    if (actual !== anterior) {
      ordernarIguales();
      count = 1;
    } else {
      count++;
    }
    anterior = actual;
  }
  ordernarIguales();
  return arreglo;
  
  //
  
  function ordernarIguales() {
   if (count > 1) {
      var sub = arreglo.splice(i - count, count);
      Array.prototype.splice.apply(arreglo, [i - count, 0].concat(ordenar(sub, reglas)));
    }
  }
}

//

function asc(a, b) {
  return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0);
}

function desc(a, b) {
  return a > b ? -1 : (a < b ? 1 : 0);
}

//// Demo 1
var criterios = [
  [3, desc],
  [0, desc],
  [1, desc],
  [2, asc],
  [4, asc]
];
var matriz = [
  [9,5,3,2,7],
  [7,9,5,4,3],
  [8,4,6,0,1],
  [9,9,6,2,1]
];
console.log('Demo 1');
console.log(matriz.join("\n"));
console.log(ordenar(matriz, criterios).join("\n"));

/// Demo 2

var matriz = [
  [9,5,3,2,7],
  [7,8,5,4,3],
  [8,4,6,0,1],
  [9,8,6,2,1],
  [5,9,5,3,1],
  [5,9,6,3,3]
];
console.log('Demo 2');
console.log(matriz.join("\n"));
console.log(ordenar(matriz, criterios).join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ordenar(matriz, criterios) {
  var arreglo = matriz.slice(0),
    reglas = criterios.slice(0),
    regla = reglas.shift(),
    columna = regla[0],
    criterio = regla[1];
  
  // Ordenamos por el criterio y columna
  arreglo.sort(function(a, b) {
    return criterio(a[columna], b[columna]);
  });

  // Verificamos filas iguales
  var actual,
    anterior,
    count = 1;
  for(var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    actual = arreglo[i][columna];
    if (actual !== anterior) {
      ordernarIguales();
      count = 1;
    } else {
      count++;
    }
    anterior = actual;
  }
  ordernarIguales();
  return arreglo;
  
  //
  
  function ordernarIguales() {
    if (count > 1) {
      var sub = arreglo.splice(i - count, count);
      Array.prototype.splice.apply(arreglo, [i - count, 0].concat(ordenar(sub, reglas)));
    }
  }
}

//

function asc(a, b) {
  return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0);
}

function desc(a, b) {
  return a > b ? -1 : (a < b ? 1 : 0);
}

//// Demo 1
var criterios = [
  [3, desc],
  [0, desc],
  [1, desc],
  [2, asc],
  [4, asc]
];
var matriz = [
  [9,5,3,2,7],
  [7,9,5,4,3],
  [8,4,6,0,1],
  [9,9,6,2,1]
];
console.log('Demo 1');
console.log(matriz.join("\n"));
console.log(ordenar(matriz, criterios).join("\n"));

/// Demo 2

var matriz = [
  [9,5,3,2,7],
  [7,8,5,4,3],
  [8,4,6,0,1],
  [9,8,6,2,1],
  [5,9,5,3,1],
  [5,9,6,3,3]
];
console.log('Demo 2');
console.log(matriz.join("\n"));
console.log(ordenar(matriz, criterios).join("\n"));
```

Comment: ¿Por qué tu respuesta es una mala copia de [esta respuesta](/a/53400), la cual es completa? [es.so] **no es un repositorio de código**. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.