# ¿Como ordenar una matriz bidimensional por columnas?

Tags: php, array

Me gustaría hacer esto mismo, pero en `PHP`:

[¿Cómo ordenar una matriz bidimensional por columnas en Javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/49116/c%C3%B3mo-ordenar-una-matriz-bidimensional-por-columnas-en-javascript)

```
array= [
//Columnas:   0 1 2 3 4
/*Filas: 0*/ [9,5,3,2,7],
/*       1*/ [7,9,5,4,3],
/*       2*/ [8,4,6,0,1]
            ]

array = [
//Columnas:   0 1 2 3 4
/*Filas: 0*/ [8,4,6,0,1]
/*       1*/ [9,5,3,2,7],
/*       2*/ [7,9,5,4,3],
            ]
```

¿Como lo puedo hacer?

He intentado hacer algo así:

```
// Intento adaptar la función a PHP
function comparar($a, $b) {
   return ($a[$ordenar] >= $b[$ordenar]) ? 1 : -1;
}

//Ordenar por la tercera columna
$ordenar = 2;

// Intento ordenar con usort, no se si se tiene que utilizar otro metodo
$lista = usort($lista, comparar);
```

Pero me devuelve:

> Use of undefined constant compare - assumed 'comparar' in

Comment: Al final lo he conseguido con usort($lista, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['ordenar'] - $b['ordenar'];
 }); Pero me ordena de menor a mayor y yo lo quiero al reves de mayor a menor

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer `return $b[‘ordenar’] - $a[‘ordenar’]`? Para que devuelva el orden contrario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer problema es que en `PHP` no puedes acceder a una variable definida fuera de la función sin antes definirla dentro de la misma como [`global`](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global); Algo que en `JS` no es necesario.

Por otro lado, la función [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php) devuelve un booleano, por lo que al hacer `$lista = usort($lista, comparar);` la variable `$lista` tendrá el valor:

> `TRUE` en caso de éxito o `FALSE` en caso de error.

Finalmente, el error que recibes es porque deberías pasar a `usort` el nombre de la función como un `String` o la función en si (*no el nombre*).

### Solución:

Teniendo en consideración lo anteriormente mencionado podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php

// Intento adaptar la función a PHP
function comparar($a, $b) {
   global $ordenar;
   return ($a[$ordenar] >= $b[$ordenar]) ? 1 : -1;
}

//Ordenar por la tercera columna
$ordenar = 2;

// Intento ordenar con usort, no se si se tiene que utilizar otro metodo
$lista = [
    [8,4,6,0,1],
    [9,5,3,2,7],
    [7,9,5,4,3],
];
usort($lista, 'comparar');

//
var_dump($lista);
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/IIKW17536)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que quieres és simplemente ordenar por la primera columna:

```
$array =array([8,4,6,0,1], [9,5,3,2,7],[7,9,5,4,3]);
//Ordeno ascendente
sort($array);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

//Ordeno descendente
rsort($array);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Resultado:
Ascendente:

```
 Array
 (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 9
        [2] => 5
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 6
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 2
        [4] => 7
    )

)
```

Descentende

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 2
        [4] => 7
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 6
        [3] => 0
        [4] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 9
        [2] => 5
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 3
    )

)
```